# Magento search result redirects to the same page with a 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: forms, magento, search, redirect, http-status-code-302

Everytime I try to search something with either the mini or advanced search form of Magento 1.7 I get not just nothing but a redirection 302.

I've spent the whole day looking for someone who had solved the same issue with no success.

And when I try http://******.net/catalogsearch/result/ redirects me to the homepage.

Update: When I change the form method to POST it works, but I need it working with GET.

Comment: the link given by you is pointing to which server? is it your local server? don't use "hehehe" kind of phrases in your questions

Comment: Did you check search terms from admin side ? adminhtml->catalog->search term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you first need to check in related controller( ResultController  Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController ) indexAction function whether that code is getting executed or not.

If not then you need to check your .htaccess file

Comment: indexAction is been executed but it seems like it's not getting the GET request()... I mean "q=books" doesn't appear so Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery() it's null. In the .htaccess file there's no any redirections nor uri exclusions. The redirection is executed by indexAction once detects there's no query to show. Suggestions?

Comment: When I change the form method to POST it works, but I need it working with GET.

Comment: How you rebuilt .htacess file again? I am having the same issue search redirecting to same page

Comment: @oscprofessionals
We have face the same issue. We have checked the Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController and .htaccess file. Everything fine but redirect to home page. How to solve this issue.